# Facing java heap space error on Hive

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

While trying to just copy data from one existing table to new table with Create table clone as select * from t_table, its working just perfect. On the other hand while trying to copy data from existing table to another existing table with Insert into table_clone select column1,col2.... from t_table, its throwing Heap space error. Source tables are same in both cases.

I have tried different size for the Container, Mapper, reducer, mapreduce.map.java.opts -Xmx5124m so on but its throwing same error every time.

few setting are :

yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb : 4GB

yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb : 6GB

Container memory ( yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb ) : 18 GB

mapreduce.map.memory.mb : 6 GB

mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb : 8 GB

mapreduce.map.java.opts : -Xmx5124m

mapreduce.reduce.java.opts : -Xmx6144m

I am not able to copy data from non partitioned table to another non partitioned table. Though main requirement is to copy from non- partitioned table to partitioned table.

Here i am attaching the yarn log on some file hosting sites in parts
1. http://textuploader.com/522pt
2. http://textuploader.com/522pq
3. http://textuploader.com/522ph
4. http://textuploader.com/522pf

We are using Cloudera quickstart which has MapReduce2 embedded into the setup.

Comment: The *entire stack trace* from the YARN logs would be much more interesting than the properties you have shown.

Comment: Also, do you use MapReduce or TEZ? Is the error a plain "OutOfMemory" or is the GC involved? Occurs in a Mapper, in a Reducer, or in the AppMaster *(container _00001)*?

Comment: And what do you mean by "Container memory"??????????

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter i have edited the question